# Passbook: cannot access Pass Type IDs in iOS Provisioning portal

Tags: ios, passbook

I am going through the tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/20734/beginning-passbook-part-1

It instructed me to go to the iOS Provisioning Center on apple's dev site, but I cannot locate *Pass Type IDs* that they refer to. I am new to apple development, so appreciate advice from those with more experience.

---

I guess my question is, can I play with / test passes, without having the $99 iOS developer account?

Comment: You must pay the $99 fee to be able to generate certificates, do push notifications, etc. If you are interacting with Apple services or want to see your code work on a device you have to pay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to developer.apple.com.
Go to member center.
Login if you need to.
Go to iOS Provisioning Portal.
On the left hand side you'll see the following

```
-Certificates
-Devices
-App Ids
-Pass Type Ids
-...
```

Pass Type Ids is what you want.

Comment: In the _member center_ I see a panel with 4 options:
Dev Centers, Dev Videos, Bug Reporting, Dev Support.
Does it mean I need to sing up for the iOS dev membership - the one that costs money?

Comment: Yes you're going to have to signup for the developer account.